# How do you include a self-contained SQLite database within an HTML5 mobile application?

Tags: html, sqlite

I know, I know, HTML5 mobile browsers include this support now, so why would anyone want to include their own?  As anyone reading this is aware, WebDB is deprecated and IndexedDB is next.  I am simply trying to be able to have my applications that use WebDB (and therefore, essentially, SQLite) continue to work with a minimum amount of re-writing if/when the mobile browsers all adopt IndexedDB.

I have been reading as much as I can, but can't find the answer to whether or not this is possible with an HTML5 application using Javascript.  It seems possible in a C environment, but that is not what I am looking for.